# How to exclude foreign keys types in reflection?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2012

I am trying to exclude foreign keys when looping through an Object.

I am looping through the entity via the code below, but I am un-sure as to how to exclude the foreign keys.

```
private static void Map<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            //If statement to exclude for foreign keys
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
        }
    }
```

This is the Generated Entity,

```
public partial class ShiftTimes
{
    public ShiftTimes()
    {
        #region Generated Constructor
        #endregion
    }

    #region Generated Properties
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateData { get; set; }

    public int? YearNo { get; set; }

    public int? MonthNo { get; set; }

    public int? DayNo { get; set; }

    public int? StaffNo { get; set; }

    public string SecondName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public DateTime? TimeDataOne { get; set; }

    public DateTime? TimeDataTwo { get; set; }

    public string Code { get; set; }

    public int? Terminal { get; set; }

    public string SubSection { get; set; }

    public string Shift { get; set; }

    public Guid? ShiftId { get; set; }

    public Guid? StaffMemberId { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Generated Relationships
    public virtual ShiftCount ShiftShiftCount { get; set; }

    public virtual StaffDetail StaffMemberStaffDetail { get; set; }

    #endregion

}
```

Any push in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you configuring foreign key in code

Comment: Without knowing how you differentiate your FK properties (since C# isn't a relational database and doesn't have the concept of foreign keys), it's difficult to advise.

Comment: @John, I updated the question with the Generated entity

Comment: If this is all the information you have, I think you'll have to determine if the type of the property belongs to `System` (since the value types you'll encounter, string, and Guid are all defined in `System`). If they aren't defined under `System` then it's probably a related object and defined in your code.

Comment: public Guid? ShiftId { get; set; }
public Guid? StaffMemberId { get; set; } Are these foreign keys in the entity?

Comment: @John, Ahh, that is it. Thanks. If you want to post that as an answer I will upvote it.

Comment: @neeleshbodgal, See `#region Generated Relationships` in the code in the question

Comment: It is? OK :) I will!

Comment: Please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.isvirtual?view=netframework-4.8) this has an answer for your navigation properties. Assuming all navigation properties are virtual

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all of the basic data types you'll get from an SQL database (`int`, `bool`, `string`, etc.) are within the `System` namespace, I expect you can just filter to only include property types in the `System` namespace:

```
private static void Map<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        if (prop.PropertyType.FullName.StartsWith("System.")) // check if the property is in System.***
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How navigation properties like "public virtual ShiftCount ShiftShiftCount" will be filtered?

Comment: @neeleshbodgal Is `ShitCount` in the `System` namespace?

Comment: My concern is how it decided whether all navigation properties will be defined in system? If not how will suggested solution will work?

Comment: @neeleshbodgal It's an SQL database, right? So the fields map to [these types in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings). Can you see any here that aren't in `System`?

Comment: I understand all types are defined in system namespace. So can this be used in to filter foreign/navigation properties.? OR an asssumption needs to be mentioned that for all foreign/navigation would be present in system namespace, the suggested solution. Moreover from the question it is not clear in which namespace naviagtion properties exsits.

Comment: @neeleshbodgal Methinks you ignored the preamble to my answer where I stated all basic types (i.e. not foreign entities) would be in the `System` namespace. Anyway [these are the assemblies](https://rextester.com/WKQQNT48823) for all of the corresponding types in .NET listed on the page I linked above. And why would OP define their entity models in the `System` namespace?

Comment: i got it. In case if property ShiftCount is not defined in system namespace how would one filter?

Comment: @neeleshbodgal Add a `!` to the `StartsWith` check?

Comment: I feel it would be enough as questioner is worried about virtual navigation properties as he/she described  in one the comments.

Answer (score 1):

If all your Foreingkeys are marked virtual you can check for that flag to be true on the GetMethod of the property.

From the PropertyInfo we obtain the [GetMethod](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getmethod?view=netcore-3.1) that will give us an [MehthodInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?view=netcore-3.1). On the base class of that instance you'll find the [IsVirtual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodbase.isvirtual?view=netcore-3.1) boolean to be set to true if a member is marked virtual.

This still is somewhat brittle because I expect you to be free to mark other members in your POCO to be virtual without having EF to throw-up. In that case you might need an extra check. The one offered by checking namespaces the type lives in might then better work for you.

This will work for your example entity:

```
private static void Map<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo prop in entity.GetType().GetProperties())
    {
        // foreignkey properties are marked Virtual
        // so its GetMehod will have that bit set.
        // see note 1*
        if (prop.GetMethod.IsVirtual)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(prop.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

and when we execute above method with

```
Map(new ShiftTimes());
```

this outputs:

> ShiftShiftCount
>   StaffMemberStaffDetail

---

<sub>1. There are maybe case that GetMethod can be null but none of those that I envision would occur for the specific use case. A null check for GetMethod is therefor left out on purpose.</sub>

Comment: This is also a solid way to do this. Thanks